# interrupt paradigms (MSI/MSI-X and legacy) in drivers

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, interrupt, interrupt-handling

Suppose a PCI hardware supports three available interrupt paradigms:

- Legacy pin based INTx
- MSI
- MXI-X

I'd like to support all three modes in my driver and pass an `intr_type` argument in `module_param()` macro. I'm wondering what is the general rule of thumb: if by default the command line parameter is empty, support MSI or MSI-X?
Since MSI and MSI-X are logically close, which one should be preferable to use?

For instance: if the driver detects that the device supports MSI-X, is this sufficient to try enable MSI-X and use it in driver, and in case of failure revert to the legacy INTx ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

INTx interrupts are likely to be shared, so the driver always has to check if its own device is the interrupt source. Typically, you want to avoid that.

MSI-X was designed to overcome some shortcomings of MSI. If you don't know what those are, then it's likely that they do not matter for your driver, and you can choose either one.

Comment: thanks for comments. I'm aware that MSI-X allows up to 2048 interrupts to be allocated by a device. Other then that both MSI and MSI-X act similar, correct?

Comment: There are other differences, but they are indeed similar.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you can just query the endpoint capabilities for MSI/MSIX support.

grep for: `PCI_CAP_ID_MSI`and `PCI_CAP_ID_MSIX`

You should fallback from MSIX to MSI and to INT if it's not supported.